# Best method to share your mobile device's screen for demo purposes?

Tags: presentation

Firstly please excuse me and redirect me if this is the wrong community.

I am finding it increasingly relevant to be able to share my mobile device's screen (Android or iOS) while presenting from my laptop (OSX). I am familiar with Chrome's "Inspect Devices", however this doesn't include some items outside of Chrome, such as Push Notifications. What would you recommend?

Comment: question probably better suited for superuser.com. I flagged it so it would be moved, otherwise maybe in https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/. good luck

Answer (score 0):

There's a Chrome extension called Vysor for Android devices.

Comment: I tried it (free version) but found it very problematic.